# Install Ubuntu 13.04 while having win-7 and linuxmint installed

Tags: installation, dual-boot, windows-7, wubi, mint

The complete question is,

I have Windows 7 installed as primary/default OS on my PC and i have installed linuxmint using wubi under windows.
And now I want to install Ubuntu 13.04 so that I can start working on it but I dont want to lose the previous installations!

Is it possible to install ubuntu either by wubi or as standalone by not loosing any data/installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a normal dual boot with Windows and Ubuntu. It won't know about or care about the Mint4Win install that you have.

You cannot use Wubi as it shares some key files with Mint4Win e.g. `C:\wubildr.mbr` and more importantly `C:\wubildr`, which is the boot file that directs you to either `\ubuntu\disks\root.disk` or the Mint4Win equivalent. It can only boot one or the other, so you'd have to manually swap it out, or alternatively add manual Grub entries in one of the Wubi or Mint4Win installs to boot the other (more pain than it's worth).

Comment: Okay thanks! and one more thing can I transfer the Mint4Win installation to Dual Boot without loosing the data. Actually in Mint4Win i'm facing some problems while the same installation on a different system is working fine in dual boot! Ignore it if sounds dumb!

Comment: @spanecostar There is a [Wubi migration script](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MigrateWubi), but it hasn't been tweaked to work on `Mint4Win` (even though it would be fairly minor to do this). You could always refer to these [manual instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MigrateWubiManually) which shouldn't require tweaking, but I don't recommend for general use.